# Double quotes keep coming in csv when merging file in python, how to remove?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, formatting, double-quotes

I have many files with URL links and I want to merge them all into one big file. The links in the inidividual files do not have double quotes around them. The merged file somehow added double quote to each link in the final csv (MergedURLs.csv). I read up the csv module documentation for python, and added the line "writeFile = csv.QUOTE_NONE", but it made no difference.

```
import csv

def mergeFile(a, b, x, y):
    for loop1 in range(a, b):
        for loop2 in range(x, y):
            try:
                fileName1 = "FoundValidURLs_"
                fileName2 = "_"
                fileName3 = ".csv"
                fileNameComplete = fileName1 + str(loop1) + fileName2 + str(loop2) + fileName3

                with open(fileNameComplete, "rb") as f:
                    for URLrecords in f: 
                        with open("MergedURLs.csv", "ab") as fi:
                            writeFile = csv.writer(fi)
                            writerFile = csv.QUOTE_NONE
                            writeFile.writerow([URLrecords])

            except IOError:
                continue
            loop2 += 1
        loop1 += 1

mergeFile(1, 2, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working now, a line is needed to remove the unnecessary, added double quote (hidden and only at the end of each url).

```
with open(fileNameComplete, "rb") as f:
    for URLrecords in f: 
        with open("MergedURLs.csv", "ab") as fi:
            writeFile = csv.writer(fi)
            URLrecords_strip = URLrecords[0:-1] # strip away the quotation at the end
            writeFile.writerow([str(URLrecords_strip)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `csv.QUOTE_NONE` as an argument to your writer, not assign to a separate variable:

```
writeFile = csv.writer(fi, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: Hum, I did try that before my current code, and it returned some error: _csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

Comment: @KubiK888: You need to have some way to allow it to include the characters it needs to include.  Did you try setting an escape character?  Is there a reason you need the resulting files to not use quotes?

Comment: I tried to do something like this: writeFile = csv.writer(fi, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\', quotechar='\"'). But it created some strange behaviour by actually adding "\\" to the end of each link. I have another python script without specifying anything else, and output each link without the double quote in the final csv file (so I really don't know why this is happening). I need the link to be seen without the unnecessary double quotes as I have another python script that uses urllib2 to open each url up, but now it doesn't recognize the link with the added double quotes.